# Why here does my use of GetOwner() make UE4 crash editor?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal

I am new to Unreal Engine. I am following a tutorial where at the end he challenged me to build some extra features to the game.

Basically. This code crashes UE4, but I found out if I remove "GetOwner()->" from the code it works just fine.

But I struggle to understand why this is. I understand that maybe the 'Switch' variable is already at Root level (ie. is the Owner already) but surely the GetOwner() function could just return itself in that scenario?

Here is my function (The line causing crash is 4th line of actual code below. If I make it "    UBoxComponent* SwitchCollider = Switch->FindComponentByClass();" instead, the game works perfectly:

```
float UDoorOpener::GetCurrentWeightOnPlate()
{
float TotalMass = 0;

// Find all the overlapping actors
TArray<AActor*> OverlappingActors;
UBoxComponent* SwitchCollider = Switch->GetOwner()->FindComponentByClass<UBoxComponent>();
if (SwitchCollider)
{
    SwitchCollider->GetOverlappingActors(OUT OverlappingActors);

    if (OverlappingActors.Num() > 0)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("MOFOOOOO"));

        // Iterate through them and add mass to total
        for (AActor* Element : OverlappingActors)
        {
            float ObjectMass = Element->FindComponentByClass<UPrimitiveComponent>()->GetMass();
            TotalMass += ObjectMass;
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s has mass of %f. Total Mass currently: %f"), *Element->GetName(), ObjectMass, TotalMass);


        }
    }
}
else
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("SwitchCollider is null!"));
}



return TotalMass;
```

}

Comment: We dont know the type of Switch or how its value is populated. It's owner may very well be null.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, sorry for delayed reply. It is definitely not null. Switch is just an Actor_BP in the scene and i confirmed it is there dragged in details panel. Also the code does work once GetOwner() is removed. The BP has a static mesh component and a boxcomponent which is set as Trigger.

Comment: If its just an actor in the scene then its owner is very likely null.

Comment: Logging can help a lot - log the getOwner output, most/some if the objects dont even have any owners - thus the getOwner should be encapsulated within IsValid() if case.

Comment: aah ok thanks guys.  i wiill try to figure this out. I think i am confusing 'Root Component' with 'Owner' types. ....Some more learning ahead of me yet.